# Micronaut's Netty server: OOM error : Leak suspect in io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache and io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop

Tags: java, out-of-memory, netty, micronaut

Can anyone please chime in whether this issue was encountered OOM error while using Micronaut's Netty server?

The leak suspects shown in Eclipse memory analyzer points to 
`io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache` and `io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop`

```
232 instances of "io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache", loaded by "jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader @ 0x71b769e00" occupy 45,436,224 (46.54%) bytes. 

233 instances of "io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop", loaded by "jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader @ 0x71b769e00" occupy 25,004,368 (25.61%) bytes.
```

### Stacktrace:

```
[7324.589s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[03:32:21.838] ERROR i.m.s.DefaultTaskExceptionHandler - Error invoking scheduled task for bean [io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.HealthMonitorTask@4e56d6cb] unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:803)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1354)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.scheduling.instrument.InstrumentedExecutorService.submit(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.AsyncSingleResultPublisher$ExecutorServiceSubscription.request(AsyncSingleResultPublisher.java:98)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:656)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.AsyncSingleResultPublisher.subscribe(AsyncSingleResultPublisher.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:163)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$IteratorSubscription.slowPath(FlowableFromIterable.java:236)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$BaseRangeSubscription.request(FlowableFromIterable.java:124)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:117)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribe(FlowableFromIterable.java:69)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromIterable.java:47)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter.subscribeActual(FlowableFilter.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe.subscribeActual(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:36)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.HealthMonitorTask.monitor(HealthMonitorTask.java:98)
    at io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.$HealthMonitorTaskDefinition$$exec1.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:146)
    at io.micronaut.inject.DelegatingExecutableMethod.invoke(DelegatingExecutableMethod.java:76)
    at io.micronaut.scheduling.processor.ScheduledMethodProcessor.lambda$process$5(ScheduledMethodProcessor.java:125)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[7624.677s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[03:37:21.925] WARN  i.m.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache - Exception thrown when submitting maintenance task
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:803)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.createWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1329)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1352)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.signalWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1476)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.push(ForkJoinPool.java:852)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.externalSubmit(ForkJoinPool.java:1919)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.execute(ForkJoinPool.java:2453)
    at io.micronaut.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.scheduleDrainBuffers(BoundedLocalCache.java:1419)
    at io.micronaut.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.performCleanUp(BoundedLocalCache.java:1452)
    at io.micronaut.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$PerformCleanupTask.run(BoundedLocalCache.java:3328)
    at io.micronaut.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$PerformCleanupTask.exec(BoundedLocalCache.java:3315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
[9605.137s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[04:10:22.372] ERROR i.m.s.DefaultTaskExceptionHandler - Error invoking scheduled task for bean [io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.HealthMonitorTask@4e56d6cb] unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:803)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1354)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.scheduling.instrument.InstrumentedExecutorService.submit(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.AsyncSingleResultPublisher$ExecutorServiceSubscription.request(AsyncSingleResultPublisher.java:98)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:656)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.AsyncSingleResultPublisher.subscribe(AsyncSingleResultPublisher.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:163)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$IteratorSubscription.slowPath(FlowableFromIterable.java:236)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$BaseRangeSubscription.request(FlowableFromIterable.java:124)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:117)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribe(FlowableFromIterable.java:69)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromIterable.java:47)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter.subscribeActual(FlowableFilter.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe.subscribeActual(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:36)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.HealthMonitorTask.monitor(HealthMonitorTask.java:98)
    at io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.$HealthMonitorTaskDefinition$$exec1.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:146)
    at io.micronaut.inject.DelegatingExecutableMethod.invoke(DelegatingExecutableMethod.java:76)
    at io.micronaut.scheduling.processor.ScheduledMethodProcessor.lambda$process$5(ScheduledMethodProcessor.java:125)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```